# Observable data gone after changing routes back and forth

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs, angularfire

I have been working on an Angular application. I have a `events.service` that contains a method `getEvents()` which returns an Observable of type `Event` from the Angular Firestore Collection I have.

In my `homepage.component`, my `getEvents()` method subscribes to `valueChanges()` of the event collection, which stores the collection into my local variable of Array `Event`.

Now, it works very fine, and the subscription is flawless. Any document I add, modify or delete from Firestore is updated in my client in real time. Very cool stuff.

The problem is when I route to a different page, and then navigate back to my homepage, my local variable is empty! I don't know why.

Here's my code:

**app.module.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: "", redirectTo: "/login", pathMatch: "full" },
    { path: "login", component: LoginComponent },
    { path: "signup", component: SignupComponent },
    { path: "home", component: HomepageComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    {
      path: "reservepage/:id",
      component: ReservePageComponent
    },
    { path: "scan", component: ScanPageComponent },
    { path: "create", component: CreateEventPageComponent },
    { path: "preview/:id", component: PreviewEventPageComponent }
  ];
```

**event.service.ts**

```
    // Angular imports
    import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

    // Angular Fire Imports
    import {
      AngularFirestore,
      AngularFirestoreCollection,
      AngularFirestoreDocument,
      fromDocRef
    } from "angularfire2/firestore";
    import { AngularFireAuth } from "angularfire2/auth";
    import * as firebase from "firebase";

    // Internal imports
    import { Event } from "./event";
    import { AuthService } from "../auth/auth.service";

    // rxjs imports
    import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";
    import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: "root"
    })
    export class EventsService {
      constructor(
        private angularFirestore: AngularFirestore,
        private authService: AuthService,
        private firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth
      ) {}

      collection: AngularFirestoreCollection<
        Event
      > = this.angularFirestore.collection("events");
      collection$: Observable<Event[]> = this.collection.valueChanges();

      document: AngularFirestoreDocument<Event>;
      document$: Observable<Event>;

      id: string;

      add(
        _name: string,
        _description: string,
        _photoURL: string,
        _address?: string,
        _totalTickets?: number,
        _ticketsSold?: number,
        _ticketsAvailable?: number
      ) {
        this.collection
          .add({
            id: "",
            name: _name,
            description: _description,
            photoURL: _photoURL,
            uid: this.firebaseAuth.auth.currentUser.uid,
            address: _address,
            totalTickets: _totalTickets
          })
          .then(docRef => {
            this.collection.doc(docRef.id).update({
              id: docRef.id
            });
            this.setId(docRef.id);
          });
      }

      getEvents(): Observable<Event[]> {
        return this.collection$;
      }

      getEvent(id: string): Observable<Event> {
        // return a document as a type
        this.document = this.collection.doc(id);
        this.document$ = this.document.valueChanges();
        return this.document$;
      }

      setId(id: string) {
        this.id = id;
      }

      getId() {
        return this.id;
      }
    }
```

**homepage.component.ts**

```
// Angular Imports
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

// Internal Imports
import { AuthService } from "../../auth/auth.service";
import { NavbarComponent } from "../../components/navbar/navbar.component";
import { EventCardComponent } from "../../components/event-card/event-card.component";
import { Event } from "../../event/event";
import { EventsService } from "../../event/events.service";

// AngularFire imports
import { AngularFirestore } from "angularfire2/firestore";

// rxjs imports
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

// firebase
import * as firebase from "firebase";

@Component({
  selector: "app-homepage",
  templateUrl: "./homepage.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./homepage.component.css"]
})
export class HomepageComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private eventsService: EventsService,
    private afs: AngularFirestore // public navbar: NavbarComponent
  ) {}

  events: Event[] = [];
  myEvents: Event[] = [];

  eventsFilled: boolean;

  getEvents(): void {
    this.eventsService.getEvents().subscribe(events => {
      this.events = events;
      console.log("the length of the events pulled are: " + this.events.length);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getEvents();
    console.log(
      "the length of the events logged from onInit are: " + this.events.length
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your ngInit firing when you navigate back? If so it may be that there are no changes to your observable, so your variable never gets repopulated. See if you can explicitly get the value out of your event service on page load.

Answer (score 3):

Are you referring to a local variable in the component?

If so, when you navigate away from a component, that component is destroyed. Any state that it had in any properties (local variables) are gone. You can't retain state in a component between routes.

Instead, you can store that state in a service. If you register the service with the root application injector, then that service will remain even when the component is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe is because you are having the subscription in the component, when you navigate the component can be destroyed (depend of how you manage the route), if it is like that then the subscription will be created every time